# Prevent from Header View from being clicked in List View?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm adding a header view to my list view initially, and have a onItemClick listener set up like so:

```
SimpleAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(_context, bookList, R.layout.list_view, 
                             new String[]{ "name","summary", "published" },
                             new int[] { R.id.bookTitle,R.id.bookSummary,R.id.bookPublished });
mBookList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mBookList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {                   
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> bookMap = (HashMap<String,String>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        String url = bookMap.get("site_url").toString();
        String bookName = bookMap.get("name").toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(_context, BookViewClass.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        intent.putExtra("name", bookName);

        _context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Issue is, when the header view is clicked I get a crash, all other cells work properly. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What do you mean with "header view"? The Name? Also, can you tell us which line causes a crash? You can find the crash info in Logcat.

Comment: Header view as in I did this: mBookList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.bookListView);
  View bookListHeader = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
    R.layout.list_view_header, null);
  mBookList.addHeaderView(bookListHeader);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ItemClickListener you can just check to see if the position is 0 and ignore it.

Comment: Do you have an OnItemClickListener?

Comment: the code above I thought was my OnItemClick listener? I tried wrapping everything inside it in an if conditional "if (position != 0) {}" but no luck, still crashed.